# WooCommerce add email order meta field just for email to admin "new order"

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added a custom field to all WooCommerce order mails but i dont want it to be shown to the emails to the customer bust just to the admin (new order mail).

```
/*----------------------------------------------
    Add Delivery Date Field to the order emails
-------------------------------------------------*/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 0, 3 );

function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields[ 'birthdate' ] = array(
        'label' => 'Geburtstag',
        'value' => $order->get_meta( '_billing_birthdate' )
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$sent_to_admin = 1`, email being sent to admin, `$sent_to_admin = 0`, email NOT being sent to admin.

```
    function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields($fields, $sent_to_admin, $order) {
        if ($sent_to_admin) {
            $fields['birthdate'] = array(
                'label' => 'Geburtstag',
                'value' => $order->get_meta('_billing_birthdate')
            );
        }
    
        return $fields;
    }
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 0, 3);
```